# splash screen in Jquery mobile android app

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i have an android app that uses jquery mobile in my web based up. i have a couple of page in my app and i was thinking of putting a splash screen on my app when i load a new page. or when the pages is being load. any suggestions on how to make a splash screen?I'm new in jquery mobile so i need suggestions. I've tried using "$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()" but it does not cover the one i want it only shows a message what i want is a whole with an image that fills the entire page. and when the page is ready the splash should just fade out and show the page that is being loaded

this fiddle is an example of "$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()" : http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/Nvrhb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    function doWork(){
        //Append a lot of paragraphs
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            $("div[data-role=content]").append("<p>This is some long string</p>");
        }
        $("div[data-role=content]").trigger("refresh");
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){

        $("#btn1").click(function(){

            $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"Please wait...", textonly:true, textVisible: true});

            //Do something lengthy here
            setTimeout(function(){
                doWork();
            }, 50);

        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a id="btn1" href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="flip">Do work</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nWWqT/

Comment: something like that omar..can the loading page thing be shown a couple of times..like every time there is a change in page or a loading occurs the loading page shows and when the page is ready the loading page fades out and the pages shows up?

Comment: sure, you can use `$.mobile.loading('show/hide')` anytime you want.

Comment: i dont have time today but i will certainly try it tomorrow when i have time.thank you as always omar

Comment: here's a fully working one http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/B2fB6/ you're welcome, always :)

Comment: @Omar is it possible to make the loading page load an image i tried doing $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.image = "image/bg.png"; but it didn't work and it is possible to run it every load of page not just at click of a button\

Answer (score 0):

If you use the phonegap(to bulid an app using jquery mobile and javascript) then you simply add the following in your main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
    }
}
```

Just add your splash page image in your /drawable folder..

Hopefully it works for you..

Comment: i tried making it i was able to make it work but my problem is when the web based app loads and the change in the pages of the web based app occurs the splash screen does not work i need a splash screen in the jquery web based app itself thank you for the suggestion though really appreciate your effort